# vm.js error but no such file exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Error Screenshot]

I'm running into this error while trying to run my JavaScript app. I've searched throughout the project and can find no file named `vm.js`.

My apologies if this is trivial, but I could find nothing relevant through Google or Stack Overflow (or Bing LOL).

Any help would be appreciated, and please link me to relevant information if it exists!

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`vm.js` is the [VM module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) for NodeJS. This error has nothing to do with that though. It's coming from the routes.js file on line 41.